Powershell: Saving output to variable
I want to save an output to a variable, but it saves more characters than I want to save.
I use:
$InstallLocation1 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%FAS%"' |  Select InstallLocation
But then my variable contains:
 @{InstallLocation=C:\Program Files\inray\FAS\}
But the content I need is:
C:\Program Files\inray\FAS\


In short: Select-Object (select) by default returns a [pscustomobject] instance that has the requested properties - even when you're only asking for a single property. To get only that property's value, use the -ExpandProperty parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) -Property parameter. See the linked duplicate for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use (...).SomeProperty


... |Select-Object <propertyName>,... will create a new object and copy the properties from the input object to the new object - so you end up with a new object that has exactly 1 property named InstallLocation.
To grab only the value of a single property, use ForEach-Object -MemberName instead:
$InstallLocation1 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%FAS%"' |ForEach-Object -MemberName InstallLocation

Alternatively you can (ab)use Select-Object's -ExpandProperty parameter to achieve the same outcome:
$InstallLocation1 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%FAS%"' |Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstallLocation

